# Reflect return values

Tags: go, reflection

I am having a few issues with return values on a call, I have the below

```
err := reflect.ValueOf(a.a).MethodByName(gatherList[x]).Call([]reflect.Value{})
```

The issue is with the return value which is nil

I can't do the usual error check as I get the following.

```
cannot convert nil to type reflect.Value
```

when I try to print the contents of err i get;

```
[<error Value>]
```

not really sure how to move forward with this error check, any help would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Value.Call()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Call) calls the function represented by the value, and returns a *slice* which represents the return values of the function (it must be a slice as in Go functions and methods may have multiple return values). The returned slice is of type `[]reflect.Value` (so its elements are of type `reflect.Value` and not `interface{}`).

If your function or method returns an error too, you may examine the corresponding element in the returned slice. You may use [`Value.Interface()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface) to obtain the value as an `interface{}` from the `reflect.Value` value.

See this example:

```
type My int

func (m My) Get() error {
    return nil
}

func (m My) GetError() error {
    return fmt.Errorf("artificial error")
}
```

Calling `My.Get()` never returns an error (it returns `nil`), and calling `My.GetError()` always returns a non-`nil` error.

Calling them with reflection:

```
methods := []string{"Get", "GetError"}
for _, m := range methods {
    result := reflect.ValueOf(My(0)).MethodByName(m).Call(nil)
    err := result[0].Interface()
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println("No error returned by", m)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Error calling %s: %v", m, err)
    }
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6I8tSEcQtV)):

```
No error returned by Get
Error calling GetError: artificial error
```

Comment: Perfect, I did note that I could just do "if result[0].Interface() == nil" and remove the need to have the intermediary var, but solved my issue nether the less, thanks.

Comment: @JohnDowling Yes, of course you can do that, I broke it to multiple lines to show the steps and make it easier to understand.